# WhatsApp notification showing "Deleting all messages"

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-on5

My father has a Samsung Galaxy On5, Android 6.0.1-Marshmallow.

Today, all of a sudden, the WhatsApp on his phone started showing this:

[image]

I quickly restarted the phone, but the notification again came back after some time. Moreover, although it's saying it's deleting messages, no message is actually being deleted from any chat or group.

Has anyone faced something like this before? Is it some malware that's causing this? I performed a check of the phone by Malwarebytes, but everything seems to be okay.

Comment: Never heard of this. But I'm wondering what happens when you press on the notification? Does it open any WhatsApp setting that would explain this? Is he using Whatsapp beta?

Comment: No not beta. And the interesting fact is that, nothing happens even if I press on the notification. Everything is working normally. It's been one hour, but the notification is still intact. Can't even swipe and remove it.

Comment: @beeshyams phone not charging, battery was about 60%, 87% used on device storage.

Comment: Ok. 87% used is a pointer. Here is my **guess** WhatsApp does local backup everyday supposedly at 2 am but the time is not confirmed. Users have reported at different times  and also observed by me//

Comment: Local backup was attempted by WhatsApp but failed since storage was low (87%) . Backup can fail for this reason as per WhatsApp FAQ. So what has probably happened is that backup attempted, failed and WhatsApp cleaning the leftovers from attempted backup. That's why no messages got actually deleted. To confirm this theory, see if it actually did a local backup in early hours. If it is not there then this guess hold weight

Comment: I'll check that when father returns, but I can provide this much information: in father's phone, the WhatsApp folder is of 200MB, while in mine, it's near about 300MB. My storage is 92% used. But WhatsApp still creates the local backup without trouble.

Comment: Did you ever find out what it was?

Comment: It kept on showing the same thing. I reported a bug at whatsapp through feedback. Just after the latest update, it's not happening any more.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the blocking "deleting all messages" notification:

1. Go to Settings - Apps - WhatsApp
2. Press "Force stop"

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Setting - Apps - WhatsApp
2. Turn off the notification
3. Clear all the notification (interface or desktop)
4. Turn on the notification again

Answer (score 1):

Fixes-

1. Open settings->App management (depends on ur system). Now find Whatsapp from the list. Then tap that and click Force stop.
2. If above step did not work, then try reinstalling Whatsapp from Play Store. Your data won't be lost.
   Hope this helps